# SQL practice and solve exercises

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Recently, I started learning SQL, and I am looking for ways to practice and solve exercises.

I searched, but I did not find any good exercises to solve, they were easy and not complicated .

Did anyone know where I could practice and solve complicated exercises in SQL ?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finding to learning basics of Sql commands is available in many sites. So i am sharing basics, intermediate and advance sql resources.

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/30-days-of-sql-from-basic-to-advanced-level/
- https://bytescout.com/blog/20-important-sql-queries.html
- https://www.1keydata.com/sql/advanced.html
- https://towardsdatascience.com/twenty-five-sql-practice-exercises-5fc791e24082
- https://learnsql.com/blog/ways-to-practice-sql-online/
- https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-sql-query-practice/
- https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/